# Chartboost Android integration - how to listen for ad loaded

Tags: java, android, ads, chartboost

I'm now integrating many ad services in my Android app, and it's the time for Chartboost.

I've just integrated AdMob, Ironsource, InMobi, MoPub, Vungle, UnityAds and Facebook, but in the Chartboost getting started guide I noticed a big difference on how to integrate it.
For example all previous services have listeners for ad loaded, started, finished, closed and in case of rewarded video, rewarded. 
I don't see any of these listeners on Chartboost.

So how can I listen for ad loaded and rewarded?
I have an Activity only for showing ads, and I choose what service to use in onCreate method.

This is the docs https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/android.
Can anyone put an example? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the delegate callbacks for the Chartboost. Please check the guide here https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/android-2